# What should I pass as a parameter?

Tags: iphone, uiview

The UIView class has a class method:

```
+ (void)transitionWithView:(UIView *)view duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

It's the first time I've seen an argument like the animation and completion arguments. What do I write in this place:animations:(void (^)(void))animations ? What does (^) and void mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your are seeing there is Objective-C's [block](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/) syntax.  The syntax is completely obtuse, frustrating, and mind-numbing, but what it is doing is actually very simple.

A block is logically equivalent to a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) in other languages such as JavaScript, so ignoring the nasty syntax you can think of the signature being something along the lines of:

```
function transitionWithView(view, duration, options, animationFunction, onComplete);
```

...where `animationFunction` and `onComplete` are closures (or blocks, to use the Objective-C parlance).  Basically you can think of them as function pointers that preserve the state of the context in which they are created.

Anyhow, the `(^)` token in Objective-C simply denotes a block.  The type that precedes it denotes the return-type of the block (so `void` in your example, meaning that neither block returns a value), and the types that follow it in parenthesis denote any arguments that the block takes (so none for `animations`, and a `BOOL` called 'finished' for the `completion` block.

Answer (score 6):

The `^` character denotes a c block. Blocks are code chunks that get executed whenever function requires it. I'm not sure about `animations:` parameter, but `completion:` block gets executed (as name states) when animation ends.

The possible call could look like this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:myView 
                  duration:1.0 
                   options:0 
                animations:^{} /* this denotes empty block */
                completion:^{ 
                                NSLog(@"Animation has completed");
                           }
];
```

Comment: +1 for insight. Blocks = closures in Objective-C. New and imo great feature for the language. http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/7/28/ios4-blocks-1